# SplashScreen not loading png file for pwa using ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen, capacitor

I used a png file for my splash screen for mac, but the image does not load. The app loads and works, it's the splashscreen with png file that's not working.

I have following on my index.js file :

```
  if (useSplashScreen) {
splashScreen = new CapacitorSplashScreen(mainWindow, {
  imageFileName: 'splash.png',
  windowHeight: 800,
  windowWidth: 600,
  loadingText: 'Starting Pinpoint...',
  backgroundColor: '#cc0099',
  textPercentageFromTop: 85
});
splashScreen.init();
```

}

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this (I have the same issue)? It's like it doesn't understand where to look for the image (inside splash_assets) or something. The loadingText and everything else works fine but the image just won't show.

Answer (score 0):

try to add splash screen in you config.xml for your browser.

```
 <platform name="browser">
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="assets/img/loading_screen.svg" />
</platform>
```